# oci_connect on PHP 5.2.0-8 not working with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-call-interface, php-5.2

I was using PHP 5.2.0-8+etch16 / oci_connect to connect to my company's Oracle DB and show information on our website (accessible to external IPs). Ever since we upgraded our DB version (to 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0), I cannot connect to the database anymore.

The page stays loading (`oci_set_call_timeout` doesn't work), and nothing is shown. I know the code works and the credentials are OK because I use the same code in another page (visible only to internal IPs) and I didn't have any problems after the upgrade. I'm using the following code:

```
$conn = oci_connect('user', 'password', 'server', 'charset');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    echo "Error";
}
else{
    echo "OK";
}
```

Running phpinfo, the oci section returns:

```
oci8
OCI8 Support    enabled
Version     1.4.5
Revision    $Revision: 305257 $
Active Persistent Connections   0
Active Connections  0
Oracle Instant Client Version   11.1
Temporary Lob support   enabled
Collections support     enabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
oci8.connection_class   no value    no value
oci8.default_prefetch   100 100
oci8.events Off Off
oci8.max_persistent -1  -1
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics    Off Off
oci8.persistent_timeout -1  -1
oci8.ping_interval  60  60
oci8.privileged_connect Off Off
oci8.statement_cache_size   20  20
```

In the page accessible only to internal IPs, the version of `oci` is 1.4.9 and it is running on a Windows Server 2003 (I know it's old). The external page (the one that doesn't work) has an `oci` version of 1.4.5 and runs in a Linux jedi-ng 2.6.25. I don't have access to the linux server (only to the folder where the php/html is stored), but I can run some things using `shell_exec()`.

Is it a version problem (I cannot connect to Oracle 11g using an old version of php/oci anymore) or this is just a connection problem that I can solve by trying another approach?

Feel free to ask questions if you need to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- Add this to the top of your test script and see if you get a better error message:

  ```
  error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  ```
- The key thing is the version of the Oracle libraries used by PHP OCI8, not the version of the database that you are connecting to.  There is a bit of overlap in some environments because the libraries could be used from the database software installation.  If you have a remote database then PHP OCI8 may (should) use the libraries from [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html) (that link is for the 64-bit packages - use the 32-bit Instant Client if you are running 32-bit PHP).
- Unless you have [OCI8 PHP 2.2.2](https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=oci8&release=2.2.0) and are using Oracle client libraries 18c or later, then `oci_set_call_timeout()` won't be available.
- If I read your question correctly, you have a problem on Linux?  In that case make sure that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set correctly for your version of the webserver, e.g you might need to set it in `/etc/sysconfig/httpd` (I don't know your Linux flavor, so this may differ).  Often it is much easier to use `ldconfig` as shown in the Instant Client [installation instructions](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html#ic_x64_inst)